# Android drag and drop, API<11

Tags: android, api, drag

i'm new in android (till now 3 weeks) and I have a problem(of course). 
I searched a lot and found few topics about that problem, but didn't get the right answer.

I can't use clipdata in api<11 so i removed that section completely from my code. 
And replaced clipdata in view.startDrag with null. And everything works fine for API >=11.
But for API level below 11, i get a error.

I don't know why(posible dragEvent???) because i don't get any message that any method in
my code isn't compatible with API level 2.2 or something. My code is:

```
public class GlavnaAktivnost extends Activity {
String linije[] = { "141 - SAMOBOR - Rakov Potok - JAGNJIĆ DOL",
        "142 - SAMOBOR - Klake - TERIHAJI",
        "143 - SAMOBOR - Rude - BRASLOVJE",
        "144 - SAMOBOR - Smerovišće - LIPOVEC",
        "145 - SAMOBOR - SLANI DOL",
        "146 - SAMOBOR - Otruševac - VRHOVČAK", "147 - SAMOBOR - BREGANA",
        "148 - SAMOBOR - OTOK", "149 - SAMOBOR - MEDSAVE",
        "150 - SAMOBOR - Grdanjci - Kršlin - GORNJA VAS",
        "150A - SAMOBOR - Grdanjci - NORŠIĆ SELO",
        "151 - SAMOBOR - Sv. Nedelja - ZAGREB (ČRNOMEREC)",
        "153 - SAMOBOR - Sv. Nedelja - ZAGREB (LJUBLJANICA)",
        "155 - SAMOBOR - Sv. Nedelja - ZAGREB (AUTOBUSNI KOLODVOR)",
        "157 - SAMOBOR - Sv. Martin - GALGOVO",
        "158 - SAMOBOR - Cerje - BUKOVJE",
        "159 - ZAGREB (SAVSKI MOST) - Galgovo - DREŽNIK / SV. MARTIN",
        "160 - MALA GORICA - Kerestinec - ZAGREB (A. K.)",
        "162 - SAMOBOR - Sv. Nedjelja - Novaki - Rakitje - ČRNOMEREC",
        "260 - LULIĆ - Jastrebarsko - ZAGREB (SAVSKI MOST)",
        "260A - JASTREBARSKO - Krašić - PRIBIĆ",
        "261 - KLINČA SELA - Repišće - NOVO SELO",
        "262 - PISAROVINA - KLINČA SELO",
        "263 - ZAGREB (SAVSKI MOST) - Kupinečki Kraljevac - DONJA KUPČINA",
        "264 - JASTREBARSKO - Klinča Selo - ZAGREB (A. K.)",
        "265 - PISAROVINA - LIJEVO SREDIČKO",
        "266 - PISAROVINA - Lučelnica - Vukomerić - DUBRANEC",
        "267 - KLINČA SELA - BETER", "KALJE - KOSTANJEVAC - KALJE",
        "SOŠICE - JASTREBARSKO - SOŠICE",
        "SVETA JANJA - JASTREBARSKO - SLAVETIĆ - SVETA JANA" };
String favoriti[] = { "Dodaj favorit +", "", "" };
MyDragEventListener myDragEventListener = new MyDragEventListener();
ListView list1, list2;
int i = 0;
int pozicija;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1, adapter2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pozadina);
    inicijalizacijaIinterface();

    list2.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MyDragShadowBuilder myShadow = new MyDragShadowBuilder(view);
            try{view.startDrag(null, // ClipData
                    myShadow, // View.DragShadowBuilder
                    linije[position], 0);// Object myLocalState
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


            pozicija = adapter2.getPosition(linije[position].toString());

            return true;
        }
    });
    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "samobor.samoborcek.RasporedVoznje");
                intent.putExtra("LIN", 143);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void inicijalizacijaIinterface() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(GlavnaAktivnost.this,
            R.layout.listview, favoriti);

    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(GlavnaAktivnost.this,
            R.layout.listview, linije);
    list2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    list1.setOnDragListener(myDragEventListener);
    list2.setOnDragListener(myDragEventListener);
    list1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE == event.getAction())
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    });

}

public void paraf() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (i == 1) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 82);
        params3.bottomMargin = 20;// Jedna linija
        list1.setLayoutParams(params3);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 18);
        list2.setLayoutParams(params4);
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 66);
        params3.bottomMargin = 20;// Dvije linije
        list1.setLayoutParams(params3);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 34);
        list2.setLayoutParams(params4);
    }
    if (i == 3) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params5 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 49);
        params5.bottomMargin = 20;// 3 linije
        list1.setLayoutParams(params5);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params6 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 51);
        list2.setLayoutParams(params6);
    }

}

private static class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
    private static Drawable shadow;

    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) {
        super(v);
        shadow = new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(140, 102, 255, 255));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point size, Point touch) {
        int width = getView().getWidth();
        int height = getView().getHeight();

        shadow.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        size.set(width, height);
        touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        shadow.draw(canvas);
    }

}

private class MyDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            if (v == list1) {
                i++;
                paraf();
            }
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            if (v == list1) {
                i--;
                paraf();
            }
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            // Gets the item containing the dragged data

            // If apply only if drop on buttonTarget
            if (v == list1 && i <= 3) {

                favoriti[i - 1] = linije[pozicija].toString();

                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                while (pozicija + 1 < linije.length) {
                    linije[pozicija] = linije[pozicija + 1].toString();
                    if (pozicija + 1 == linije.length) {
                        linije[pozicija] = " ";
                    }
                    pozicija++;

                }

                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (v != list1 || i > 3)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nedozvoljeno!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

QUESTION: What is wrong? Or can you tell me please, how to make that if API level is above 11 do something, and if not do the other thing?
 Because MyDragEventListener is constructed outside any of methods, and if i construct it in example onCreat, it wouldn't be global so it wouldn't be visible in any other method.

I solve it for now, that i creat 2 other activities, first activity is main screen...And if api level is example 2.2 start this activity(in this activity i use if item on list2 is long clicked send data to list1(NO DRAG AND DROP)) and if it is 4.3 start other activity(DRAG AND DROP).

P.S. I know that this code is lame, and i don't know why i just don't watch that paraf() method, i will fix it later :)
Thank you,
Matija

Comment: Please strip your code to show only the relevant parts.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post the logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

[View.OnDragListener was introduced with API level 11](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html). Trying to create an instance of the MyDragEventListener class (which derives from it) will crash on a pre-Honeycomb device.

You can check the API level and act accordingly with the android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT field, e.g.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{
    MyDragEventListener myDragEventListener = new MyDragEventListener();
    ...
}
```

Same with the View.DragShadowBuilder, &c.